# How to handle tap on row of 2nd tableView which is under the 1st table view cell in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

First Table View Image 1 ->

[image]

Second table view (Which is nested in 1st Table View) Image 2 ->

[image]

First row of nested table view working after tap but others are not working Image 3->

[image]

When I tap on 1st row of 1st `tableView` then it is working properly and when I tap on 1st row of second `tableView` then it is also working.

**Problem is when I tap on 2nd row of 2nd tableView then it is not working.**

Same as if second row of 1st table view is taped then in 2nd tableView only 2nd row is working when tap.

```
class CartVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    var selectedIndex = -1  
    var nestedSelectedIndex = -1 

    var nestedTableViewCellDataTitle : [String] = ["ABC123", "DEF456","GHI890","JKL145"]
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView.tag == 1{
            return 5
        }
        else{
            return nestedTableViewCellDataTitle.count
        }

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if tableView.tag == 1{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CartTableViewCell
            cell.nestedTableView.delegate = self
            cell.nestedTableView.dataSource = self

            return cell
        }else {
             let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NestedCartTableCell", for: indexPath) as! NestedCartTableCell
            cell.productTitle.text = nestedTableViewCellDataTitle[indexPath.row]

            return cell
        }

    }


    //Hide and Open when we tap on table view
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if tableView.tag == 1{
            if selectedIndex == indexPath.row{
                selectedIndex = -1
            }else{
                selectedIndex = indexPath.row
            }
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()

            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)

            self.tableView.endUpdates()
        }else if tableView.tag == 2{
            if nestedSelectedIndex == indexPath.row{
                nestedSelectedIndex = -1
            }else{
                nestedSelectedIndex = indexPath.row
            }
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)

            self.tableView.endUpdates()
        }

    }

    //Specify hight for both view
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if tableView.tag == 1{
            if selectedIndex == indexPath.row{
                return 500

            }else{
                return 37
            }
        }else{
            if nestedSelectedIndex == indexPath.row{
                return 410
            }else{
                return 106
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: It isn’t very clear what your question is about. Can you illustrate with some images?

Comment: As per your code I can see only two condition on didSelect method have you handle 3 condition for 3rd table in list ?

Comment: there is only two tableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Create new variable of type UITableView. Store nested tableView form 1st TableView cell and then reload this table when tap on row on nested tableView.

class CartVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
var selectedIndex = -1  
var nestedSelectedIndex = -1 

var nestedTableViewCellDataTitle : [String] = ["ABC123", "DEF456","GHI890","JKL145"]


var newTableView = UITableView() **//This is the key (Solution Line 1)**



 var requestForMatchineStyleImage : [String] =["BAGS","BANGLES","BELTS","BRACELETS","CUFFLINKS","EARRINGS","FINGER-RINGS","HEADBANDS","KEYRINGS","NECKLACES","STRINGS"]


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView.tag == 1{
        return 5
    }
    else{
        return nestedTableViewCellDataTitle.count
    }

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView.tag == 1{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CartTableViewCell
        cell.nestedTableView.delegate = self
        cell.nestedTableView.dataSource = self

        newTableView = cell.nestedTableView //**This is the key (Solution Line 2)**

        return cell
    }else {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NestedCartTableCell", for: indexPath) as! NestedCartTableCell
        cell.productTitle.text = nestedTableViewCellDataTitle[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

}


//Hide and Open when we tap on table view
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    //let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)


    if tableView.tag == 1{
        if selectedIndex == indexPath.row{
            selectedIndex = -1
        }else{
            selectedIndex = indexPath.row
        }
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()

        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)

        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }else if tableView.tag == 2{
        if nestedSelectedIndex == indexPath.row{
            nestedSelectedIndex = -1
        }else{
            nestedSelectedIndex = indexPath.row
        }
        self.newTableView.beginUpdates() **//This is the key (Solution Line 3)**
        self.newTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic) **//This is the key (Solution Line 4)**

        self.newTableView.endUpdates()**//This is the key (Solution Line 5)**
    }

}



//Specify hight for both view
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if tableView.tag == 1{
        if selectedIndex == indexPath.row{
            return 500

        }else{
            return 37
        }
    }else{
        if nestedSelectedIndex == indexPath.row{
            return 430
        }else{
            return 106
        }
    }

}


@IBAction func backArrowBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true
        , completion: nil)
}


@IBAction func backTextBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}



static func storyboardInstance() -> CartVC? {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "CartSt", bundle: nil)
    return storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as? CartVC
}



override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

}

extension CartVC : UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return requestForMatchineStyleImage.count
    }

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCellOfRFQ", for: indexPath) as! RFQNestedCollectionViewCell

    return cell
}
```

}